# Is it stalking to pay someone's bills?

Tags: criminal-law

I am paying a girls bills who has a restraining order against me, is it stalking/harrasment to pay her bills when she won't contact me?

Comment: I don't understand: the contract is in your name but you moved out? Or do you want to stalk here by paying her bills because she has a chance thus letting her know that you are still around her? The former is a quite different situation from the latter...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe, maybe not. The answer is implicit in the restraining order, which I assume you have a copy of. If the wording is unclear, you can ask your attorney. The order will state the consequences for violating the order, so you have some idea what the risk factor is. A person may also petition for a new restraining order to include bill-paying, which may or may not be granted.